# How to correctly set up iWARP? Preferably on loopback

Tags: linux, cluster, infiniband

iWARP is a protocol for doing remote direct memory access (RDMA) on top of TCP/IP, so that it can work with Ethernet and other network types as opposed to Infiniband. It works with many of the standard IB interfaces - the IB verbs, for example - so it's all pretty transparent.

I'm doing some IB-verbs programming (mostly for the sake of learning about how they work better), and it'd be wonderfully convenient for me if I could use iWARP to do RDMA over my loopback interface, so that I could test some of my code without getting on our IB-connected cluster. :-)

But I cannot figure out how to get a "local development environment" set up: there are no tutorials I'm aware of for even setting up iWARP from scratch on a server or a network interface. Can anyone give me a tutorial or point me in the right direction?

Environment is Fedora 16 running in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you can run iWARP software you need either a network interface that supports iWARP in hardware or a software implementation of iWARP. A software implementation of iWARP can be found here (not yet included in OFED): http://gitorious.org/softiwarp.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have already looked at it, but if not, take a look at [OFED](https://www.openfabrics.org/resources/ofed-for-linux-ofed-for-windows/ofed-overview.html).  There you will find probably the best resource for getting iWarp or RoCE up and running regardless of the environment (though I can't guarantee you will go through the guide without some hand wringing).

To save you from pulling some of your hair out (either during setup up or more importantly when developing and tinkering) I would suggest at least making another virtual machine and then test using those two machines.

Best of luck.